# iOS CoreBluetooth: Connect with peripheral by own service

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to create mobile app (iOS) which should connect with peripheral and control the streaming data. I connect and discover peripheral services and characteristics. But problem is that the peripheral enables streaming only if it gets *setNotify* from central's characteristic with specified UUID (and its service also needs to have specified UUID).

Is it possible to set in mobile app a central with service and characteristic, where both (service and characteristics) have specified UUID?
Is it possible to do with CoreBluetooth or I should use something else?

---

Tag starts streaming data within its service's (UUID: AAA1-...) characteristic (UUID: AAA2-...) **ONLY IF** its *Notify* property will be set by central's charecteristic with specified UUID (UUID: XXX1-...)

Comment: The central does not have services or characteristics. It discovers the services and characteristics of a peripheral and the reads/writes and subscribes to those characteristics.